# Jenkins Parameterised Job with Terraform map variable

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, terraform

I'm trying to feed user-defined parameters from Jenkins into a job which runs terraform. I have a set of simple key/value vars, which I'm passing into the Terraform like this:

```
sh "terraform plan -var 'var1=${params.Var1}' -var 'var2=${params.Var2}' ...."
```

However, I also have a map var:

```
tags = {
  Cluster     = "mycluster"
  Environment = "myenv"
  Owner       = "owner"
  Product     = "myproduct"
}
```

and I would like to feed some String Parameters into this map var. It looks like I need to define a groovy map and then render the map as JSON, so that I can have e.g. `terraform -var 'tags={"Cluster":"mycluster","Environment":"dev"...}`

My job is currently of the form:

```
pipeline {

    agent {
    ...
    }

    options {
    ...
    }

    environment {
    ...
    }
    stages {

        stage('MyStage') {
            steps {
              script {
                sh "terraform ..."
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'me very new to Jenkinsfiles, so where would I define a map, if that's what was needed..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt in the question is close, but Maps in Groovy are constructed with `[:]`. Therefore, you can construct a Jenkins Pipeline Map type output in JSON to be passed to a Terraform Map type like the following:

```
terraform -var "tags=${JsonOutput.toJson(['Cluster':'mycluster', 'Environment':'dev'...])}"
```

Given your use of the `sh` step method above, you will also need to escape your quotes to properly cast your strings appropriately as well.